# Language rules for table, figure captions

Tags: captions, languages

In the following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\renewcommand{\tablename}{Tabula}

\begin{document}
Dažādu I tipa pusvadītāju kritiskā temperatūra dota \ref{Tab:Tcr}. tabulā:

\begin{table}[ht]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{l l}
    materiāls              & T [K]\\
    \hline
    Sn                     & 3,7 \\
    Pb                     & 7,2 \\
    Al                     & 1,2\\
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{``Pusvadītāju kritiskā temperatūra''}

  \label{Tab:Tcr}
  \end{table}

\end{document}
```

with the command `\renewcommand{\tablename}{Tabula}`I renamed "Table" by "Tabula", in this case to accommodate to the Latvian language.

The output is here:
[image]

I still would need to change "Tabula 1" to "1. tabula" ("2. tabula" ... "10. tabula") to accommodate to the Latvian language better.

How to achieve this?

Comment: If you  load `babel` with option `latvian`, you have it out of the box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\usepackage[latvian]{babel}`. This should rename your table caption to "1. tabula: ...". So you don't have to try to rename it yourself, and can leave out the `\renewcommand{\tablename}{Tabula}`.